# Make a duplicate of a facebook share popup

Tags: html, facebook

I try to make a duplicate of the share button on the following site (it's at the bottom):

WARNING! THE IMAGES ON THIS SITE CAN BE VERY DISTURBING!!!
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/special/2014/newsspec_8702/index.html

If I click from there it looks like this:
[image]

If I copy the code:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=58567469885&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fmodules%2Fsharetools%2Fcallback%3Fst_cb%3Dfacebook%23state%3Dfeed&amp;display=popup&amp;link=http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-29205427&amp;name=Voices%20from%20the%20mall%20-%20remembering%20the%20first%20terrifying%20hours%20of%20the%20Westgate%20attack%20a%20year%20ago%2C%20via%20%40BBCNewsMagazine&amp;description=Shared%20via%20BBC%20News&amp;picture=http://newsimg.bbc.co.uk/media/images/67373000/jpg/_67373987_09f1654a-e583-4b5f-bfc4-f05850c6d3ce.jpg" target="_blank"><span>Facebook</span>
</a>
```

And put it in a html or jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/6oufc1pL/

Then instead of a popup I get a new window and the image is gone:
[image]

Why is that? And how can I change this behavior.

edit:

If I click the popup on the original site the link changes to this for some strange reason:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=58567469885&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fmodules%2Fsharetools%2Fcallback%3Fst_cb%3Dfacebook%23state%3Dfeed&display=popup&link=www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-29205427&name=Voices%20from%20the%20mall%20-%20remembering%20the%20first%20terrifying%20hours%20of%20the%20Westgate%20attack%20a%20year%20ago%2C%20via%20%40BBCNewsMagazine&description=Shared%20via%20BBC%20News%20Magazine&picture=http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/special/2014/newsspec_8702/static/img/fb.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `picture=` to `image=` like this:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=58567469885&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fmodules%2Fsharetools%2Fcallback%3Fst_cb%3Dfacebook%23state%3Dfeed&amp;display=popup&amp;link=http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-29205427&amp;name=Voices%20from%20the%20mall%20-%20remembering%20the%20first%20terrifying%20hours%20of%20the%20Westgate%20attack%20a%20year%20ago%2C%20via%20%40BBCNewsMagazine&amp;description=Shared%20via%20BBC%20News&amp;image=http://newsimg.bbc.co.uk/media/images/67373000/jpg/_67373987_09f1654a-e583-4b5f-bfc4-f05850c6d3ce.jpg" target="_blank"><span>Facebook</span>
</a>`

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yeah but strangely enough I get a different image :)
But at least it's better. Still wonder why there is no popup.

Comment: I know Facebook caches the og:image tag, could this be why `picture=` wasn't working? Maybe force a scrape of new information from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

Comment: In regards to opening as a pop up, use some Javascript like the following:

`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" >Share this</a>`